# SharpDX: Create a D3D11.Texture2D from D3D10.Texture2D?

Tags: directx, sharpdx

I'm using SharpDX and trying to create a `D3D11.Texture2D` that points to the same data as an existing `D3D10.Texture2D`. I think that I need to get a `DXGI.Surface` and use that to create the new texture, but I always get this unhelpful error:

> HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [Unknown], ApiCode: [Unknown/Unknown], Message: The parameter is incorrect.

Here's my current code that compiles but doesn't work:

```
private D3D11.Texture2D CreateD3D11Texture2D(D3D10.Texture2D d3d10Texture2D)
{
    var texDesc = new D3D11.Texture2DDescription
    {
        ArraySize = 1,
        BindFlags = D3D11.BindFlags.ShaderResource | D3D11.BindFlags.UnorderedAccess,
        CpuAccessFlags = D3D11.CpuAccessFlags.None,
        Format = DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
        Height = d3d10Texture2D.Description.Height,
        MipLevels = 1,
        OptionFlags = D3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
        SampleDescription = new DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
        Usage = D3D11.ResourceUsage.Default,
        Width = d3d10Texture2D.Description.Width
    };

    SharpDX.DataRectangle dataRectangle;
    using (var surface = d3d10Texture2D.QueryInterface<DXGI.Surface>())
    {
        int pitch = d3d10Texture2D.Description.Width
            * (int)DXGI.FormatHelper.SizeOfInBytes(d3d10Texture2D.Description.Format);
        dataRectangle = new SharpDX.DataRectangle(surface.NativePointer, pitch);
    }

    return new D3D11.Texture2D(this.d3d11Device, texDesc, dataRectangle);
}
```

**Update**

I came across an answer that outlines [how to share surfaces between different DirectX devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071915/1339280). Based on that, I believe the correct way to get a `D3D11.Texture2D` from a `D3D10.Texture2D` is to get a resource interface and call `OpenSharedResource()`.

Doing that simplifies my function quite a bit:

```
private D3D11.Texture2D CreateD3D11Texture2D(D3D10.Texture2D d3d10Texture2D)
{
    using (var resource = d3d10Texture2D.QueryInterface<DXGI.Resource>())
    {
        return this.d3d11Device.OpenSharedResource<D3D11.Texture2D>(resource.SharedHandle);
    }
}
```

It seems to work. Is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To share data among multiple textures, get a `DXGI.Resource` interface, and then call `OpenSharedResource()`. Here's how do it with SharpDX:

```
private D3D11.Texture2D CreateD3D11Texture2D(D3D10.Texture2D d3d10Texture2D)
{
    using (var resource = d3d10Texture2D.QueryInterface<DXGI.Resource>())
    {
        return this.d3d11Device.OpenSharedResource<D3D11.Texture2D>(resource.SharedHandle);
    }
}
```

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071915/1339280) to another question with more general information about sharing surfaces between different DirectX devices.