# Share surface between D2D, DX10, DX11

Tags: c++-cli, directx-11, direct2d, directx-10, spritefont

I need to share surface between direct 3d 10.1 device and direct 3d 11 device to permit my application to render Sprite sharing surface between diirect 2d and direct 3d 10.1.
I've read this topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554(v=vs.85).aspx
but ther is only example for sharing between d2d and d3d 10.1 and not for sharing between d3d 10.1 and 11, can someone give me code example?

Answer (score 0):

Surface sharing between different DirecX devices is done via [`IDXGIResource::GetSharedHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ID3D11Device::OpenSharedResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485265/cant-create-direct2d-dxgi-surface/9071915#9071915) another answer that explains the process in more details.